# Why doesn't align-content / align-items work here?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I'm just trying to make a simple navbar and I just started playing around with flexbox. Why doesn't `align-content` work here? I can get `justify-content` to work but I just can't align vertically. Here's the code.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#Navbar_Wrapper {

}

#Navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: darkslategray;
}

#Navbar_Content_Wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

#Navbar_Content_Wrapper li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#Navbar_Content_Wrapper a {
    color: white;
    font: 16px normal Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS Files/Navbar.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<section id="Navbar_Wrapper">
    <div id="Navbar">
        <div id="Navbar_Content_Wrapper">
            <div id="#Navbar_Content_Left">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Forum">Forum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Search">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Why on earth doesn't this center my items vertically? Please help me out because I'm just completely stumped as to why this isn't working. Even though its probably just something simple.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have 2 problems here:

1. You're using the wrong property.  `align-content` is for distributing space between multi-line flex items (eg. using `flex-wrap: wrap`).  You're looking for the `align-items` property instead.
2. There's no extra space to distribute.  The height is set on the flex container's parent element (`#Navbar`), not the flex container itself (`#Navbar_Content_Wrapper`).  In other words, your flex container is only as tall as its contents.

http://jsfiddle.net/qdv54k6f/

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with flexboxes. Just set the line height to 300px and you're done. (Also works for non-flexboxes.)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#Navbar_Wrapper {} #Navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: darkslategray;
}
#Navbar_Content_Wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}
#Navbar_Content_Wrapper li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#Navbar_Content_Wrapper a {
  color: white;
  font: 16px normal Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
  <section id="Navbar_Wrapper">
    <div id="Navbar">
      <div id="Navbar_Content_Wrapper">
        <div id="#Navbar_Content_Left">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Forum">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Search">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Edit: or the height or course. Silly me.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#Navbar_Wrapper {} #Navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: darkslategray;
}
#Navbar_Content_Wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 300px;
  align-items:center;
}
#Navbar_Content_Wrapper li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#Navbar_Content_Wrapper a {
  color: white;
  font: 16px normal Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
  <section id="Navbar_Wrapper">
    <div id="Navbar">
      <div id="Navbar_Content_Wrapper">
        <div id="#Navbar_Content_Left">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Forum">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Search">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Navbar_Contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: If the downvoter would care to explain, maybe we could work out a deal that would get you your rep point back.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question though. I want to know how to do it with flexboxes because I'm extremely confident that's one of the purposes of using them. I know I can use line-height but I want to be able to use align-items. Or at least know why it isn't working in this case?

Comment: @DevSock Well, the navbar_content_wrapper doesn't have a height set, so it will have its default height (i.e. one line of text). There is no CSS that tells it otherwise. The flex properties won't grow the  navbar_content_wrapper to a larger height.

Comment: Just curious, did you make your edits after reading my answer?

Comment: @cimmanon Yes, but I posted my comment to the OP here first, before I did, so you can see I was already aware of the height being the problem. Or the lack of height, so to speak. By the way, I still think my original solution is the better one, because it works with and without flexboxes.